# Generate tiles from Leaflet polygons

Tags: leaflet, polygon, rasterization

I have a set of shapes drawn in Leaflet (using Leaflet.draw). I need to rasterize these into a tileset and export it because I need to use the images elsewhere.

My initial idea was to go through each polygon and create matching tiles for each tile it intersects across all zoom levels. However, if there is a library or function that exists that can do this, I'd rather use that.

Comment: What if you export/ Save as a vector layer, then use a WMS\WMTS service like GeoServer to create tiles on request?

Answer (score 0):

There are some plugin for vector tile

https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#vector-tiles

or you can show your vector features with OpenLayers library than you can get canvas element so you can cut canvas element.

Comment: Leaflet also "knows" Canvas: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#map-prefercanvas